# Auth0 login calling Youtube Data API v3

Tags: oauth-2.0, youtube-data-api, openid-connect, auth0, auth0-connection

I have an SPA application as per Auth0 SPA application definition (using Angular). I am using Auth0 as a client log in mechanism. My application allows for a user to log in with two service providers, IDP(s) or social connections: `Facebook or Google`. (Given I have supplied Client Id's and Secrets for applications under those IDP's domain) https://auth0.com/docs/connections . If a user successfully authenticates my application will return an array containing an access code which may be used to make calls to the IDP's API (https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/identity-provider-access-tokens).

The successful case: After logging in with Facebook. I can retrieve the access token and make a call to Facebook's graph API.

The problem: When logging in with Google, I can retrieve an access token. However when I use that access token to make a call to the Youtube Data v3 API, I receive an:

```
 Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

What I've tried:

- Auth0SPA's `getTokenSilently()` - I have no idea of what type this token returns. The documentation is not explicit. https://auth0.github.io/auth0-spa-js/classes/auth0client.html#gettokensilently
- Auth0ManagementAPI's `GET /user` endpoint - returns an access token which is rejected by Youtube Data API https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2?_ga=2.178387047.219514694.1599842538-835787596.1599842538#!/Users/get_users_by_id
- I've tried creating an enterprise OpenID Connect Connection via the Enterprise connections enabled by Auth0 - no identities array (which contains the access token) is returned. https://auth0.com/docs/connections/enterprise/oidc

### Questions I want answered

I've figured workarounds however they unfortunately impact the user experience. I'd like to know what getTokensSilently returns, a token for what?

What changes must I make so that I can use the access token returned by the IDP (under the identities array) to make calls to the Youtube Data v3 API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to your questions,

1. getTokenSilently returns a token by the auth0 after successful authentication of the user.
   You can use that token for

- sending to backend for authorization.
- Get user's info from auth0.

2. For using token for youtube Data API, you need to check `Youtube` in permissions in Dashboard > Connections > Social.